# migrating to sharefile V3. Recieving statusCode: 401 after authentication

Tags: rest, http, chilkat

Seattle 10
Chilkat

migrating sharefile api from V1 to V3.
Registered for API key and received credentials.
Code is successful in receiving authorization code and immediately after when sending a get request with header containing authorization code to receive list of items in a file using
GET','/sf/v3/Items('folderid)?$expand=Children&$select=Id,Name,Children,Children/Id,Children/Name',sbResponseBody)

I get a 401 error unauthorized. cannot find any help on the sharefile site.

response: Response Status Code = 401Response Header:Response Body:{"code":"Unauthorized","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"[AUTH] Invalid Authentication"},"reason":"NotAuthenticated"}
response3:

Sorry for being verbose. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting the answer to my question in case somebody has a similar issue as mine.

My issue was that I was adding the word "Bearer" to the auth id which is returned by the http request while using that auth id to download my item from sharefile.

Unlike with some others I did not have to add the word bearer to the Oauthid as the http header did it for me.